# Interpreting triple product summation as matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been wondering about this for a little while and I can't seem to come up with a definite answer. I'm leaning towards "this is not possible", but I figured I'd ask around to see if anybody else has an answer.

**Problem statement**

Given the expression (where $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$ and $c_{ij}$ are all real numbers) 
$$\sum_{i} a_{ij}b_{ik}c_{il}
$$can this be expressed in terms of matrix/tensor multiplication? If there were only two terms, such as in

$$\sum_i a_{ij} b_{ik}= (A^TB)_{jk}$$

then this would be a straightforward problem.

If there isn't a way to map this to a matrix multiplication problem, is there some other some other computationally efficient procedure for calculating such a summation with triple/quadruple terms? Or has anybody encountered some literature/terms for further research?

**Literature**

Equations of this nature come up all the time in the context of Corner Transfer Matrix Renormalisation Group (CTMRG). For example, equations (1) and (2) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1677.pdf

Comment: I think a solution, if there exist one, is by using Kronecker product operations.

Comment: Interesting. I can form a matrix $A\otimes B$ using the Kronecker product. A subset of this matrix will be elements of the form $a_{ij}b_{ik}$. If I pick out those elements and form a matrix $\widetilde{{AB}}$ with that, the remaining product will correspond to $\sum_i \widetilde{AB}_{ijk}c_{il}$, which is a standard matrix product. However, forming the full Kronecker product is a bit overkill if I just need a small subset. I wonder if there's a way to setup or trim the matrices $A$ and $B$ so that the Kronecker operation only computes what I need.

Comment: I would also suggest trying to use partial trace operator. It sounds like it could be useful here.

Comment: I thought I had a solution but I have erased it. A remark : let $M$ having all its entries $0$ except $M_{jk}=1$.
$A^TMB$ is a matricial expression for your $(A^TB)_{jk}$. If $N$ is the same kind of matrix as $M$ but for indices $l$ and $m$, we could consider $(A^TMB)^TNC$...

Comment: If I understand correctly your input are three matrices, but your output is a three-dimensional cube of numbers, where the number in position (j, k, l) of the cube is the outcome of the sum from your post for fixed j, k and l?

Comment: @Vincent Yep, that's right, although it's not strictly necessary to have the output as a cube. The important part is the fact that the summation over $i$ includes the product of 3 terms. The other indices could've all been $j$ and the underlying question would remain the same (in fact, equation 1 in the linked reference is exactly this: summation over $b$, two instances of a free index $a$).

Comment: @AlexSmart Good point. I think the "subset matrix" I defined above ($\widetilde {AB}$) is exactly a partial trace over $A\otimes B$ in the first index. This is fantastic, as even if I can't come up with a more efficient program to compute this, I at least have an intuitive / geometric explanation for these equations now!

Comment: So, your expression is just inner product of partial trace of $A \otimes B$ with some other matrix $C$? Expressions of this type are very important in quantum information.